# How to "scroll up" and view previous console output?

Tags: terminal

I am getting started using my Raspberry Pi. Sometimes I run some command where the console output scrolls off the screen too fast for me to read. For example, installing some library/package from source, I'd like to be able to review the output. However, I can't figure out how to scroll up to view the previous output. The up arrow is obviously not working. Is there a special key command, or different way to view the console output?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm putting this question on-hold as it isn't specific to the Raspberry Pi and is more of a 'generic' Linux question. For the future, [SuperUser.SE](http://superuser.com) would probably be the best place to ask.

Answer (score 24):

Shift + PageUp or Shift + PageDown keys.

Comment: You can also use scroll-lock (when using a tty) to pause the text scrolling past.

Answer (score 12):

Pipe the output of the command to `less`:

```
cmd arg0 arg1 | less
```

In `less`, you can scroll up and down intuitively with the arrow keys. Use the <kbd>Q</kbd> key (for *Quit*) to exit `less` and return to your prompt.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255070/how-do-you-scroll-up-down-on-linux-server-terminal